# Apache Commons EmailValidator and SeamListener Exception (not deploying)

Tags: maven-2, deployment, apache-commons, email-validation

When using Apache Commons EmailValidator through Maven, I have the following problem that doesn't deploy my app:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraints violated when linking org/xml/sax/EntityResolver class
```

I've used the following code at my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

One help?

Comment: Are you using mvn deploy? And how is the deploy configured? May be other components are involved as well, but i can't see them here, cause you don't added the POM.

Answer (score 0):

The `commons-validator-1.3.1.jar` artifact pulls `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` as shown below:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q2714398
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.stackoverflow:Q2714398:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `LinkageError` suggests that you have duplicate versions of `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar`, which is an obvious suspect here, on the classpath when deploying on JBoss.

Maybe simply try to exclude it from the deployed application (can't give a more precise answer with the current level of details).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```